Mypy plugin `get_method_hook` missing `body` in `ClassDef` for imported type
I'm having an issue with the get_method_hook in a simple mypy plugin. I'm not sure if it's a bug in mypy or if I have wrong expectations about the availability of information at a certain stage.
The plugin is supposed to read the properties from the class on which the invoke function is called, extract all properties from the class, and change the return type of invoke to a TypedDict that contains all properties from the class.
This works great if the class is defined in the same module in which invoke is called. If the class is defined in a different module (i.e., imported), the body (from my_type.defn.defs.body) of the imported class is not available, and thus, only limited information from the properties is available (i.e., merely the type Outer in this case, but no information about its parameters).
Here's an MWE that doesn't include the actual logic to generate the TypedDict, because that's irrelevant for the problem at hand.
# foo.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any


@dataclass
class Inner:
    a: int
    b: int


@dataclass
class Outer:
    inner: Inner


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    outer = Outer(inner=Inner(1, 2))
    outer2 = Outer(inner=Inner(3, 4))

    def invoke(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return self.__dict__

# bar.py
from my_pkg.foo import MyClass


def bar():
    b = MyClass(1, 2, 3)
    result = b.invoke()
    print(result["d"])


bar()

# plugin.py
from typing import Callable, cast

from mypy.plugin import (
    MethodContext,
    Plugin,
)
from mypy.types import (
    Instance,
    Type,
)


def alter_invoke_return_type(ctx: MethodContext) -> Type:
    my_type = cast(Instance, ctx.type).type

    for member_name, member_type in my_type.names.items():
        print(f"Member property {member_name} has type {member_type}")

    # TODO: How to wait until body from imported type has been analyzed to extract the
    # 'inner' objects of a member variable type?
    assert len(my_type.defn.defs.body) != 0, f"Type {my_type.fullname} has no body"

    return ctx.default_return_type


class CustomPlugin(Plugin):
    def get_method_hook(self, fullname: str) -> Callable[[MethodContext], Type] | None:
        parts = fullname.split(".")
        if parts[-1] == "invoke":
            return alter_invoke_return_type
        return None


def plugin(version: str):
    return CustomPlugin

There is hardly any documentation about mypy plugins. Is looking at the AST node of the ClassDef even the right approach to extract detailed information like the inner field of the outer and outer2 properties of MyClass?

that doesn't include the actual logic to generate the TypedDict, because that's irrelevant for the problem at hand. Actually, this is not correct. You should use the class's mypy.nodes.TypeInfo attribute to build the type for the TypedDict, not traverse its AST body to build the type. mypy discards the AST of all modules after analysing the type information and type-checking the contents, as otherwise it would take up too much memory, and after it discards the AST you can't traverse it again.

Thanks! The problem with mypy.nodes.TypeInfo in this case is that it doesn't contain any details about the parameters that the object was created with. It would be easy to iterate over the names of mypy.nodes.TypeInfo and build the TypedDict from it. But I'm explicitly interested in the parameters passed to the constructor of Outer here (i.e., Inner(...)). This information is stripped away when accessing the types from the names dictionary of mypy.nodes.TypeInfo. Still, what you're saying basically answers my question: mypy discards the AST after finishing a module.

In that case, you should build the TypedDictType in a hook which offers ctx: mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext - that is invoked while the class AST is still alive. Build a cache of type dict[TypeInfo or ClassDef, TypedDictType], then change the return type with get_method_hook later.

That makes sense, thank you.
